# Very slow input elements in Ant Design Form

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am using React and Ant Design for React, and I'm trying to build a form with 10 to 15 input elements. The input is very slow. I'm using their examples in the documentation as a reference and I'm not doing anything different. What might cause my problem? Here is a code for reference:

```js
const formItemLayout = {
      labelCol: {
        xs: { span: 24 },
        sm: { span: 8 }
      },
      wrapperCol: {
        xs: { span: 24 },
        sm: { span: 16 }
      }
    };

<Form inline="true" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <Row gutter={8}>
            <Col span={15}>
              <FormItem {...formItemLayout} label="Name">
                {getFieldDecorator(
                  `category[categories_langs][na5me]`)(
                    <Input/>
                )}
              </FormItem>
            </Col>
          </Row>
          
          // The above Row repeated ten-fifteen times

</Form>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Are there any other operations that you are performing not mentioned here? 10-15  form fields [should not be an issue here](https://codesandbox.io/s/q4lo12wqzj)

Comment: @BoyWithSilverWings The above code is not working, it gives this error: ModuleNotFoundError
Could not find module in path: 'core-js/2.5.1/library/modules/_fails' relative to '/node_modules/core-js/2.5.1/library/modules/_descriptors.js'. No, I'm not doing any other operations. Just putting 10/15/20 inputs like I said above, and the input is very laggy.

Comment: Something is wrong with codesandbox. Can you recheck now?

Comment: Now it gives this error: ModuleNotFoundError
Could not find module in path: 'antd/dist/antd.css' relative to '/index.js'

Comment: The input is laggy in your example too.

Answer (score 4):

This should be antd and rc-form issue. See: https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/14054

So far, a workaround is to use debounce method to improve the input experience. You can create a high-level component to wrap Input component. The lib https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-component-debounce can help you to do so. The similar code as follows:

```js
import reactComponentDebounce from 'react-component-debounce';

const DebounceInput = reactComponentDebounce({
    valuePropName: 'value',
    triggerMs: 250,
  })(Input);
```

Answer (score 2):

It may most probably be due to unnecessary re-rendering of other components every time you call `setState()`.

So to avoid the response lag:

- use `PureComponent` (you can also use `shouldComponentUpdate` lifecycle method but it's more error-prone) instead of simple `Component` when extending you class-based component
- if using functional component, use `React.memo()`

> Make sure you are using latest version of React

Answer (score 0):

Usually input is lagging when you update the state at every keystroke while focusing the input field (usually onChange event) and lag occurs because the render function belonging to the context of the changed state is re-executed, thus every component lacking of `shouldComponentUpdate` method redraws itself.

**Solution #1**
Instead of `onChange` event set data in `onBlur` event

**Solution #2**
Implement shouldComponentUpdate in every child component ti prevent unnecessary redraws

Ref: https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html

Answer (score 0):

Ant Design GetFieldDecorator does two way data binding and to do that it changes the state and re-renders each item.

The only solution is rewriting your code without GetFieldDecorator.

You can read more about it here:
https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/13063

Answer (score 0):

When you wrap your element with getFieldDecorator, you can specify it like this ⚡️

```
<Form.Item>
  {getFieldDecorator('offer_name', {
    initialValue: undefined,
    trigger: 'onBlur',
    valuePropName: 'defaultValue',
    rules: [{
      required: true,
      message: `Please enter ${vasFor} name!`,
    }],
  })(
    <OfferInputType
      label="Enter name of this offer"
      placeholder="Offer name"
      type="text"
      onBlur={this.offerNameChange}
      maxLength={45}
    />)}
</Form.Item>
```

**Trigger** prop is used to target a method from children node. In our case : **onBlur**.

**valuePropName** also targets a prop from children node. In our case defaultValue that is override by initialValue.

Note: for more information visit: [Example](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/13063#issuecomment-456069046)